# Difference between the `s` permission and the `sh` flag in `VmFlags`

Tags: linux, memory

I don't really understand the difference between both "marks" to know if a memory region is "meant to be private" or shared: the permission `s` and the `sh` `VmFlag`.

In which situations will they be set? Is there cases where the permission `s` appear but `sh` doesn't, or viceversa? Or they both appear or none does?